# How stop prisma auto-add relation to table

Tags: postgresql, prisma, relation

I have problem with vscode, and prisma:

- when I remove one relation, prisma after save file added it again.
- bellow video with problem: https://dsh.re/5bea0

I using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You would need to disable format on save setting in VS Code, continuing discussion here: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18448

Comment: thats not an answer. Why would i want to disable auto-save/format for the whole app. its stupid.